# Cannot created object walking though JSON string using Circe JSON parser

Tags: json, scala, circe

So i am trying to create a custom decoder for a JSON string to be converted into a domain object.
I am using Scala/Circe to walk through the JSON and create the object. 
I am unable to get this to run. I am sure i am not clear on how to walk through the JSON. Can someone advise please ?

This is the JSON in question ,

```
   {
  "args": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", 
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1", 
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.108 Safari/537.36"
  }, 
  "origin": "61.16.136.118, 61.16.136.118", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/get"
}
```

Here is what my code looks like,

```
    import com.softwaremill.sttp._
import com.softwaremill.sttp.circe._
import io.circe._, io.circe.parser._

case class Headers(Accept: String, Accept_Encoding: String, Accept_Language: String, Host: String, Upgrade_Insecure_Requests: String, User_Agent: String)
case class RootInterface(args: String, headers: Headers, origin: String, url: String)

object SttpClientGetPost extends App {
  implicit val backend = HttpURLConnectionBackend()

  implicit val rootDecoder: Decoder[RootInterface] =
    (hCursor: HCursor) => {
      val tcursor = hCursor.downField("headers")
      val argsCursor = hCursor.downField("args")
        for{
          args <- for{
          testString <-  argsCursor.get[String]("args")
        }yield testString

        headers <- for {
          Accept <- tcursor.downField("Accept").as[String]
          Accept_Encoding <- tcursor.downField("Accept-Encoding").as[String]
          Accept_Language <- tcursor.downField("Accept-Language").as[String]
          Host <- tcursor.downField("Host").as[String]
          Upgrade_Insecure_Requests <- tcursor.downField("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests").as[String]
          User_Agent <- tcursor.downField("User-Agent").as[String]
        } yield Headers(Accept, Accept_Encoding, Accept_Language, Host, Upgrade_Insecure_Requests, User_Agent)
        origin <- hCursor.downField("Origin").as[String]
        url <- hCursor.downField("url").as[String]
      } yield RootInterface("", headers, origin, url)
    }
  val secondRequest = sttp //.headers(("userId", USER_ID),("password","testpassword"))
    .get(uri"http://httpbin.org/get")

  secondRequest.send().body match {
    case Left(fail) => System.out.println("The Get request was unsuccessful.   " + fail)
    case Right(rawJSONResponse) =>
      parser.decode(rawJSONResponse) match {
        case Left(fail) => System.out.println("The JSON response could not be parsed by Circe.  " + fail)
        case Right(rootInterfaceObject) =>
          System.out.println("Origin :" + rootInterfaceObject.origin)

      }
  }

}
```

Update :
I am trying with this to no avail now,

```
case class Headers(Accept: String, Accept_Encoding: String, Accept_Language: String, Host: String, Upgrade_Insecure_Requests: String, User_Agent: String)
case class RootInterface(args: String, headers: Headers, origin: String, url: String)


val doc = """{
  "args": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", 
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1", 
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.108 Safari/537.36"
  }, 
  "origin": "61.16.136.118, 61.16.136.118", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/get"
}"""


  implicit val decodeHeaders: Decoder[Headers] = Decoder.forProduct6(
  "Accept",
  "Accept-Encoding",
  "Accept-Language",
  "Host",
  "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests",
  "User-Agent"
 )(Headers(_, _, _, _, _, _))

implicit val decodeRootInterface: Decoder[RootInterface] = Decoder.forProduct4(
  "args",  
  "headers",
  "origin",
  "url"
)(RootInterface(_, _, _, _))

val t = decode[RootInterface](doc)
```

I am still getting a decoding failure. It looks like its because of the `args` field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd strongly recommend building up your instances compositionally—e.g. instead of baking all of the `Headers` decoding logic into the `RootInterface` decoder, you can define a separate `Decoder[Headers]` instance and then use that in your `Decoder[RootInterface]`.

I'd also recommend avoiding working with cursors directly unless you're doing something particularly complicated that you know requires that level of definition.

So given this document:

```
val doc = """{
  "args": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", 
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1", 
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.108 Safari/537.36"
  }, 
  "origin": "61.16.136.118, 61.16.136.118", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/get"
}"""
```

…and these case classes:

```
case class Headers(Accept: String, Accept_Encoding: String, Accept_Language: String, Host: String, Upgrade_Insecure_Requests: String, User_Agent: String)
case class RootInterface(args: String, headers: Headers, origin: String, url: String)
```

…the following is a complete working example you can use in a REPL:

```
import io.circe.Decoder, io.circe.jawn.decode

implicit val decodeHeaders: Decoder[Headers] = Decoder.forProduct6(
  "Accept",
  "Accept-Encoding",
  "Accept-Language",
  "Host",
  "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests",
  "User-Agent"
 )(Headers(_, _, _, _, _, _))

implicit val decodeRootInterface: Decoder[RootInterface] = Decoder.forProduct3(
  "headers",
  "origin",
  "url"
)(RootInterface("", _, _, _))
```

…like this:

```
scala> decode[RootInterface](doc)
res0: Either[io.circe.Error,RootInterface] = Right(RootInterface(,Headers(text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3,gzip, deflate,en-US,en;q=0.9,httpbin.org,1,Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.108 Safari/537.36),61.16.136.118, 61.16.136.118,https://httpbin.org/get))
```

(I'm not sure what the intention is with the `args` decoding, so I've just followed your implementation in using the empty string.)

If you control the `Headers` case class definition, though, I'd strongly suggest using idiomatic Scala member names (i.e. camel case, not upper snake). Combining that with [circe-derivation](https://github.com/circe/circe-derivation) makes a pretty clear solution in my view:

```
import io.circe.Decoder, io.circe.derivation.deriveDecoder

case class Headers(
  accept: String,
  acceptEncoding: String,
  acceptLanguage: String,
  host: String,
  upgradeInsecureRequests: String,
  userAgent: String
)

object Headers {
  implicit val decodeHeaders: Decoder[Headers] = deriveDecoder(
    _.replaceAll("([A-Z])", "-$1").capitalize
  )
}

case class RootInterface(
  args: Map[String, String],
  headers: Headers,
  origin: String,
  url: String
)

object RootInterface {
  implicit val decodeRootInterface: Decoder[RootInterface] = deriveDecoder
}
```

And then:

```
scala> io.circe.jawn.decode[RootInterface](doc)
res0: Either[io.circe.Error,RootInterface] = Right(RootInterface(Map(),Headers(text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3,gzip, deflate,en-US,en;q=0.9,httpbin.org,1,Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.108 Safari/537.36),61.16.136.118, 61.16.136.118,https://httpbin.org/get))
```

Comment: Much thanks for the details. I will try both these approaches that you mentioned and get back to you. For starters i do not understand  what is this `implicit val decodeHeaders: Decoder[Headers] = deriveDecoder(
    _.replaceAll("([A-Z])", "-$1").capitalize`    ?
  ) doing ?

Comment: @SomBhattacharyya It transforms the member names from the Scala-idiomatic camel case (`acceptHeader`) to the incoming `Accept-Header` format.

Comment: I am unable to make the first way work. Updated my question with my code.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to decode a JSON object into a `String`. How do you want this to work?

Comment: Yeah so i am trying to make a decoder that can decode the given JSON string. What i have changed in this code is i am trying to decode the `args` field too. Is that causing this ?Are you saying i need to have a decoder for args separately ?

Comment: You're going to need some kind of mapping from JSON objects to strings for the value of the `args` field. What do you want that to look like?

Comment: Yeah i think i just got it working with a `Map[String,String]` mapping for args. I was using `String` which is not correct. Cant thank you enough for the eager help.